# My friend told me that $b \simeq o$ topologically.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

My friend told me that for two letters $b,o$ of the alphabet, we have that $b \simeq o$ topologically.

But I don't have any knowledge of topology. 
Can you recommend a text to understand (as fast as possible) the above statement?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean, that the letters 'b' and 'o' are homeomorphic?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the wikipedia page on topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology)?

Comment: @amrsa  maybe YES!

Comment: @Jo  Sorry, i haven't. Thanks for your reply. On the page, the table of ' Equivalence classes of the English' says that two closed curves (in 2-dim) with one hole are homotopic. Am i right? Then should i investigate 'homotopy'?

Answer (score 1):

They are not homeomorphic, however b **deformation retracts** on o (which roughly means that you can suck the antenna of the b back along itself till it disappears), and therefore *any* relevant invariant from algebraic topology will tell you that b and o are the same from its point of view. They are said to have the same *homotopy type*.

Comment: Why do you say they're not homeomorphic? In most typefaces each of those letters is homeomorphic to an annulus.

Comment: @Henning only if they have width. If you consider them to be 1D curves, then o is a manifold but b isn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is my understanding that when using letters as an introductory example to shapes, like on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Introduction), we are assuming the letters to be 1-dimensional.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I consider indeed the letters to be $1$-dimensional, it is very easy to grasp as a first example of deformation retracts, while the case with a width does not bring much.

Answer (score 0):

They are not homeomorphic because if such homeomorphic exist say f, then if you remove  the mid point of top antenna of “b”, it would have two connected component but removing any point from the letter “o” would still give a connected set. So such f can not exist.

Comment: You are right. i realized they aren't homeomorphic, but homotopic.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of a bee or an oh? The bee and the oh on the left in the following figure are homeomorphic, in other words: topologically the same; but the bee and the oh on the right are not homeomorphic: All small pieces of the oh are just little intervals, but the bee has two "special points".

[image]

Comment: A wise answer to a silly question! very nice. My initial question is latter in your figure.  I realized they aren't homeomorphic, but homotopic.